# how to update gradle in my android application

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hi I want to update Gradle in my android project,

File -> Project structure
Gradle version - 7.1.1

does this mean I am using nearly latest Gradle in my project?

I have seen some more reference of Gradle in my project in gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip

this might mean the same this which I saw in project structure.

what does the gradle reference in bellow lines of code mean?

```
    resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
        val pluginId = requested.id.id
        when {
            pluginId.startsWith("org.jetbrains.kotlin") -> useVersion(kotlinVersion)
            pluginId.startsWith("kotlinx") -> useModule("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlinVersion")
            pluginId.startsWith("com.android") -> useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
            pluginId.startsWith("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") -> useModule("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1")
            pluginId.startsWith("com.google.gms.google-services") -> useModule("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8")
        }
    }
}
```

gradle version seems to be `4.2.2` and 2.7.1

What does this exactly mean.

and how can I update them please

sorry if my question is vague

I want to get the project to use latest Gradle version

thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **file** -> **Project structure** and on the project tab you can select the last version of Gradle from the boxes and press ok.
then from **Gradle scripts** open **gradle-wrapper.properties** and and edit version part of **distributionUrl** manually.

Also, there is two version for Gradle, first **Android Gradle Plugin version** and second **Gradle version** you can see the latest versions in a table from bellow link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin